# aligning HTML select elements on one line

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

i am working on a mobile app using HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I have two select option (drop down menu), one for number of dates and the other one for number of years. I want to be able to see these select options in one line, but no matter what I do, I get a drop down menu (number of dates) on one line and on the next line I get the drop down menu for number of years. Below you can see my codes

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type = "horizontal" >

        <label for="select-choice-1" >Choose Expiry Date</label>
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-inline = "true" style = "float: left">
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option> 
                <option value="5">05</option> 
                <option value="6">06</option> 
                <option value="7">07</option> 
                <option value="8">08</option> 
                <option value="9">09</option> 
                <option value="10">10</option> 
                <option value="11">11</option> 
                <option value="12">12</option> 
                <option value="13">13</option> 
                <option value="14">14</option> 
                <option value="15">15</option> 
                <option value="16">16</option> 
                <option value="17">17</option> 
                <option value="18">18</option> 
                <option value="19">19</option> 
                <option value="20">20</option> 
                <option value="21">21</option> 
                <option value="22">22</option> 
                <option value="23">23</option> 
                <option value="24">24</option> 
                <option value="25">25</option> 
                <option value="26">26</option> 
                <option value="27">27</option> 
                <option value="28">28</option> 
                <option value="29">29</option> 
                <option value="30">30</option> 
                <option value="31">31</option> 
            </select>

            <select name="select-year" id="select-yaer"  data-inline = "true" style = "float: right"/>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option> 
                <option value="2015">2015</option> 
                <option value="2016">2016</option> 
                <option value="2017">2017</option> 
                <option value="2018">2018</option> 
                <option value="2019">2019</option> 
                <option value="2020">2020</option> 
                <option value="2021">2021</option> 
                <option value="2022">2022</option> 
                <option value="2023">2023</option> 
                <option value="2024">2024</option> 
                <option value="2025">2025</option> 
                <option value="2026">2026</option> 
                <option value="2027">2027</option> 
                <option value="2028">2028</option> 
                <option value="2029">2029</option> 
                <option value="2030">2030</option> 

            </select><br />

        </div>
```

UPDATE:
I am testing these codes on Android browser using jQuery mobile framework.

Comment: Is the date drop-down and 'Choose Expiry Date' label taking up all the space on the first line?

Comment: `<select>` elements are inline elements, so they'll be on the same line naturally if you don't give them any style.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question!

Comment: Do y6ou have any other CSS being applied other than that floats on the select elements?

Comment: I have used CSS within my code, but for the Select Option specifically I didnt use any CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try floating both `select` tags left and adding a `clear:both` to the styling on the `label`. If you want the `label` above the two selects, just add a `<br />` right below the label.

It would look something like

```
    <label>Label Value</label>
    <select>
        <option>Etc...</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option>Second select option...</option
    </select>
```

and the CSS would be

```
    label {
        clear:both;
    }
    select {
        float:left;
    }
```

Also, as a heads-up, you end your second `select` tag before the first `option` tag, so they aren't included.
`<select name="select-year" id="select-yaer"  data-inline = "true" style = "float: right"/>`. You need to get rid of the `/` right before the ending of the tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's the width on the ui-select class that's causing your issue, Setting the width to auto should correct the issue. jQM adds a ton of extra markup for the look and feel on the page to be consistent across multiple devices. If you view the page source in a browser such as Chrome or FireFox you can see the extra elements. In your case you needed to modify the ui-select class as it has a width of 60% as the default.

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/trdYP/47/

JS:

```
$('#select-choice-1').parent().parent().css('width','auto');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-inline="true">

            <label for="select-choice-1" data-inline="true">Choose Expiry Date</label>
                <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-inline="true">
                    <option value="1">01</option>
                    <option value="2">02</option>
                    <option value="3">03</option>
                    <option value="4">04</option> 
                    <option value="5">05</option> 
                    <option value="6">06</option> 
                    <option value="7">07</option> 
                    <option value="8">08</option> 
                    <option value="9">09</option> 
                    <option value="10">10</option> 
                    <option value="11">11</option> 
                    <option value="12">12</option> 
                    <option value="13">13</option> 
                    <option value="14">14</option> 
                    <option value="15">15</option> 
                    <option value="16">16</option> 
                    <option value="17">17</option> 
                    <option value="18">18</option> 
                    <option value="19">19</option> 
                    <option value="20">20</option> 
                    <option value="21">21</option> 
                    <option value="22">22</option> 
                    <option value="23">23</option> 
                    <option value="24">24</option> 
                    <option value="25">25</option> 
                    <option value="26">26</option> 
                    <option value="27">27</option> 
                    <option value="28">28</option> 
                    <option value="29">29</option> 
                    <option value="30">30</option> 
                    <option value="31">31</option> 
                </select>

                <select name="select-year" id="select-yaer" data-inline="true">
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option> 
                    <option value="2015">2015</option> 
                    <option value="2016">2016</option> 
                    <option value="2017">2017</option> 
                    <option value="2018">2018</option> 
                    <option value="2019">2019</option> 
                    <option value="2020">2020</option> 
                    <option value="2021">2021</option> 
                    <option value="2022">2022</option> 
                    <option value="2023">2023</option> 
                    <option value="2024">2024</option> 
                    <option value="2025">2025</option> 
                    <option value="2026">2026</option> 
                    <option value="2027">2027</option> 
                    <option value="2028">2028</option> 
                    <option value="2029">2029</option> 
                    <option value="2030">2030</option> 
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make them both float left they will sit side by side, as long as their combined widths don't exceed the width of the container.