# multiple <select> dropdowns on one line (Foundation css import)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Currently trying to get 2 dropdown `<select>` elements to sit on the same line, as they are sat one above the other no matter if I make them shorter so they could definitely fit.

I am using a third party CSS library: [Foundation by Zurb](https://foundation.zurb.com/)

I have seen this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846384/aligning-html-select-elements-on-one-line), but it didn't seem to help me.

Any suggestions?

**Run the code snipped below to see what is happening**

***NB. I do not wish to use JQuery.***

```js
const BaseUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/";
const ApiKey = "myapikey";

function buildUrlSource (source) {
    return BaseUrl + "top-headlines?sources=" + source + "&apiKey=" + ApiKey;
}
function buildUrlCountry (country) {
    return BaseUrl + "sources?language=en&country=" + country + "&apiKey=" + ApiKey;
}

const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        countries: [
            {
                name: 'Australia',
                code: 'au'
            },
            {
                name: 'USA',
                code: 'us'
            },
            {
                name: 'Britain',
                code: 'gb'
            },
            {
                name: 'Canada',
                code: 'ca'
            },
            {
                name: 'Italy',
                code: 'it'
            },
            {
                name: 'India',
                code: 'in'
            },
            {
                name: 'South Africa',
                code: 'za'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ireland',
                code: 'ie'
            }
        ],
      sources: [],
      results: [],
      loadSource: true,
      loadCountry: true,
      title: '',
      source: 'bbc-news', // Default news feed to BBC News
      country: 'gb' // Default country to Britain (gb)
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getSources('gb'); // Default to British News
        this.getPosts('bbc-news'); // Default view to BBC News        
    },
    methods: {
        getPosts(source) {
            let url = buildUrlSource(source);
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                this.results = response.data.articles;
                this.title = "Top ten headlines from '" + this.source + "'";
            }).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
            this.loadSource = false;
        },
        getSources(country) {
            let url = buildUrlCountry(country);
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                this.sources = response.data.sources;
            }).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
            this.loadCountry = true;
        },
        isLoaded() {
            return(this.loadCountry && this.loadSource);
        }
    }   
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- NEWS APP -->
<!-- https://www.sitepoint.com/fetching-data-third-party-api-vue-axios/ -->

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The greatest news app ever</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="appCSS.css">    
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container" id="app">
      <h3 class="text-center">Headline News</h3>

      <section class="callout secondary">
        <h5 class="text-center">Apply filters</h5>
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-1">
              <label>
                Country: 
                <select v-model="country" v-on:change="getSources(country)">
                  <option v-for="item in countries" :value="item.code">{{ item.name }}</option>
                </select>
              </label>
              <label>
                News Source: 
                <select v-model="source" v-on:change="getPosts(source)">
                  <option v-for="item in sources" :value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
                </select>
             </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>

    </div>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Lohr for helping me not give my API Key away XD

Comment: you can still see in in the edit history though ;)

Comment: Yup. That comment did more harm than good. I saw the key also :)

Comment: time to get a new key!

Comment: You can try putting each `label` and `select` in their own `div`, float the first `div` left and `display: block` using css.

Comment: God damnit guys! XD It's nothing important really :P

Comment: @AndrewLohr that didn't work. Although it DID get the "News Source" label onto the same line???

Comment: does each `div` contain both the label and a select?

Comment: @AndrewLohr - Yes I wrapped each of the <label><select>'s in its own <div>
I think that it may have something to do with the overall imported CSS class from a third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was using the Foundation CSS library, I did a bit of research and found that I was missing a bit of syntax on `div`s surrounding each of the `label`/`select` tags.

It looks like I was missing `medium-6` and most crucially, `columns` from my `<div>` class tags

The syntax should have been like this:

```
<div class="medium-6 columns">
   <label>Country: 
       <select v-model="country" v-on:change="getSources(country)">
           <option v-for="item in countries" :value="item.code">{{ item.name }}</option>
       </select>
   </label>
</div>
```